# What is the difference between these two loops? Why is one working and the other is not?

Tags: javascript, string, loops, for-loop

I want to know why is it that when I add a variable with a value of an empty string(") the loop works but when i remove it, the loop ...doesn't seem to loop within this function...

Here is the first loop:

```
function laugh(num) {
  var laugh = "ha";
  for (var i=0; i<=num; i++){
     laugh;
  }
  return laugh + "!";
}
console.log(laugh(3));
```

And here is the second one:

```
function laugh(num) {
  var string = "";
  var laugh = "ha";
  for (var i=1; i<=num; i++){
     string += laugh;
  }
  return string + "!";
}
console.log(laugh(3));
```

The first returns "ha!" while the second returns the correct amount of ha's ...which is "hahaha!"

why does adding an empty string make it work?
Beginner by the way...I really don't want to move on to the next lesson until I have fully understood what is going on. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

That is because all you're doing in the first loop is a statement:

```
laugh;
//Equivalent to
"ha";
```

In the second loop, you are concatenating a new string to `string`:

```
string += laugh;
```

You need to do this concatenation otherwise it will only return `ha!`:

```js
function laugh(num) {
  var laugh = "ha";
  for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    laugh += "ha";
  }
  return laugh + "!";
}
console.log(laugh(3));
```